# How to send Ajax request directly to model escaping controller step in mvc in cake php

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

i am making an application using mvc structure. In that when the controls go from controller to model step then it comes back. i want that Ajax request should go directly from model to view rather than going to controller and then to view....

Comment: Do not use cakephp...what is the point of mvc then?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you like to use the MVC pattern at all when you then want to *ignore* it? This does not make any sense at all.

Technically what you want is possible using a dispatcher filter and getting an instance of the model via ClassRegistry but bypassing the controller step disables any kind of auth checks, components and well, views as well. It totally makes no sense.

If you want to build a messy application go for the dispatcher filter or don't use a MVC framework at all.

Comment: if i just want to get only a number of counts from any table then why should i use controller??because when i use Ajax request first it goes to controller then model and comes back to controller. Its time consuming...and unnecessary activities on the server...